# Use function or function pointer when dependency is inverse?

Tags: c++, c, architecture

I'm developing a MCU (MicroController Unit) development system (which means limited space and low speed, and no operating system in my project). It is composed of 2 kinds of MCUs which play different roles in the system, and their programs are different.

They use the same underlying (static) library written in C. The library needs a callback function when it receives data from bus. The callback functions should be in the clients (C for one the C++ for another), and are also different for two programs.

What should the structure be like? Here are two solutions.

1. Declare a function in the underlying library and define it in the client. The library just calls this function.
2. Define a function which take an function pointer as a parameter and then assign to a static variable. The library calls the function by the function pointer.

Currently I'm using the second solution just because it seems to be more elegant. However, the first has higher performance, and is safer (linker will give an error if the definition doesn't exist), while the first involves an indirection and is not that safe (if I forget to register the function).

Which one should I choose? Or are there any better solutions?

Comment: Maybe the title is not suitable. If so, how to improve?

Comment: #2 is a common approach. For safety, the library can initialize the pointer to point to a dummy function that just prints an error message, or logs a fault. Once the client registers the real function, the system is ready to go, and the performance difference is minimal (assuming that message processing in the client is non-trivial).

Comment: I take it you mean a *static* underlying library? I don't think #1 would work all that well for a dynamic library...

Comment: What does MCU mean? All a Google search returns is movie-related stuff.

Comment: @JL2210 [MicroController Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller). Embedded processor basically.

Comment: My fault. MCU is microcontroller (unit), which means limited space and low speed.

Comment: @JaMiT Yes. There's no OS in the MCU (in my project, others may have), so all libraries are statically linked.